# Does the availability of pornography increase prostitution and sex trafficking?

Tags: prostitution

Rick Santorum one of the Republicans seeking the presidential candidate nomination in America [posted a piece](http://www.ricksantorum.com/enforcing-laws-against-illegal-pornography) on how and why he opposes pornography with some claims that he suggests is backed up by research (of which none is cited):

> America is suffering a pandemic of harm from pornography.  A wealth of research is now available demonstrating that pornography causes profound brain changes in both children and adults, resulting in widespread negative consequences. Addiction to pornography is now common for adults and even for some children. The average age of first exposure to hard-core, Internet pornography is now 11. Pornography is toxic to marriages and relationships. It contributes to misogyny and violence against women. **It is a contributing factor to prostitution and sex trafficking.**
>
> [..]

Is it true that research has shown that an increase in the availability of pornography leads to an increase in prostitution and sex trafficking?

Comment: The claim is not that it causes an increase.  Just that it is a factor in it.  If one former porn actress becomes a prostitute because she cant/wont find other work then it has contributed.  If a single person is trafficked for use in porn then it has contributed to that.

Comment: The actual claim is: **A wealth of research is now available demonstrating that pornography causes profound brain changes in both children and adults, resulting in widespread negative consequences.**

Comment: @Chad Well no, that's not the only claim in that paragraph. We already have a question regarding pornography and the effect that has, so it seemed redundant to be to bring that up again. Since he's using this as an example against pornography, claiming there's scientific research supporting his position in the same paragraph, then yes he is claiming that pornography increases prostitution and sex trafficking. Yes he is claiming it leads to an increase, since he's saying it's a factor and is speaking out against it. He's just not saying it's the *only* reason for such things.

Comment: I take issue with a lot of the research that is in this field due to its bias. I saw a panel discussion and 2 of the researchers made fraudulent claims (the top 50 DVDs were misogynistic gonzo, false). They are agenda based researchers, so most of the work in the field is rubbish.

Comment: @KitSunde - But saying it is a contributing factor does not mean that it causes an increase.  You do not have a valid notable claim here to support your question.

Comment: @Chad The definition of contribute is: "Help to cause or bring about." I'm not sure how you can interpret his statement as him saying it has no effect or negative effect, the alternatives are strange in the context even if the definition of contribute was different.

Comment: @KitSunde - a negative effect does not mean increase.  It is a vague claim(deliberately so I suspect) that is easy to prove (I gave 2 examples above).  You could also say that prostitution contributes to pornography.  I would also note that eating has negative consequences.  After all you get gas from certain foods, many people have food allergies, and people die every year from tainted food.  I suspect that you could not find a single action that does not have a negative consequence.  Bottom line you are asking a question that is not supported by your notable claim.

Comment: @Chad He is talking about perceived negative effects on society (i.e. increase in prostitution). Yes it's a vague claim, we deal with vague claims about woo all the time where they don't specify exactly how much this or that does. It's entirely possible that more prostitution leads to an increase in pornography *and* that pornography leads to an increase in prostitution across a whole society. I don't see why it would need only be one way. Saying everything has negative consequences is a cop-out when I'm asking for research. Either way there is a close button for the community to decide.

Comment: you do not have a claim that **research has shown that an increase in the availability of pornography leads to an increase in prostitution and sex trafficking?**!  That is required to ask a question here on skeptics. I will vote to close if you are unwilling to adjust the question.

Comment: Negative consequences is vague. Also increase of bread may increase the consumption of sandwitch. So what?

Comment: @JimThio The quote literally says "It contributes to misogyny and violence against women.", so not quite that vague. And what so what? If eating sandwiches harms you, and an increase in bread leads to more sandwiches being eaten I don't see why a "so what" would be in order.

Answer (score 8):

There is little direct evidence as to whether increased access to pornography increases prostitution or sex trafficking, but based on the evidence we have I think its more likely that porn decreases or has no effect on rape.  I link to the most rigorous research I've heard of below, but there is also the following brute fact that is hard to explain away: Access to porn has radically increased since the late 1990s with the rise of the internet... during the same time period the number of rapes in the U.S. has fallen quite a lot.

[Research suggesting access to porn decreases rape](http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/everyday_economics/2006/10/how_the_web_prevents_rape.html).

[Research suggesting access to porn increases rape](http://www.freakonomics.com/2011/08/10/more-on-rape-and-porn-does-internet-access-increase-sex-crimes/).

[More research on pornography](http://garthzietsman.blogspot.com/2012/03/pornography-intelligent-view.html).

Comment: I'd up vote you if you used some summaries or quotes from the links so we could see their key conclusions without following the links.

Comment: I upvoted you because even though it's not answering the question, you are saying something true and important. Who care if pornography increase prostitution. What matter is if it increase or decrease rape and even that is not important. Now we should start seeing those that oppose porn to prevent rape to change their stance and start making watching porn mandatory. I wouldn't settle for less.